# votes not counting for the last hour or so

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Odd thing, I did see my increased score when this answer was accepted: [What's the best way to detect an algebraic number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104356/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-an-algebraic-number/104364#104364)  but no sign of the three separate upvotes. Similar for yesterday's [Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational/104120#104120)  which had about 3 votes since mt edit of an hour ago. Neither question or answer shows me a Community Wiki indication.

I see, on the right there is a column of similar questions in Meta, I will look at some of those.

EDIT:  Maybe this is it, I looked at the FAQ, but then I also clicked on "what is reputation" and may have found it:

"The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Your peers will vote on your posts, and those votes will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
answer is voted up  +10
question is voted up    +5
answer is accepted  +15     (+2 to acceptor)
question is voted down  -2
answer is voted down    -2  (-1 to voter)

A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit. "

Ooh, that's very different. Never mind. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Litella

Comment: Yes, you've just hit the daily reputation cap. Congratulations!

Comment: Rather than editing the answer into the question, submit an answer as a separate post, an actual answer post. (:

Comment: +1 for the Emily Latella reference.

Answer (score 6):

As you've seen, there's a daily reputation cap of 200.

You can read more about reputation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: Is this still in play? I have seen users gain more than 200 rep outside of bounties.

Comment: @DisplayName The post linked to by Anna Lear says: "You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation *from upvotes and suggested edits* in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately."